# Salesforce Report - Group values by first character

Tags: reporting

Hi within standard Salesforce reporting, is there a way to group field values by the first character? I'm not finding a way so wonder if it's a limitation. Thanks!

e.g.below

Value Count
A1     1
A2     1
B1     1
B2     1
C1     1
C2     1

Value  Count
A       2
B       2
C       2

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible directly from a report. You'd have to create formula field and group by that field. The formula would be:

```
LEFT(My_Field__c, 1)
```

Comment: It depends on the data type and number of values. Bucket columns can handle simple groupings.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use [Bucket Columns](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_bucketing_overview.htm&type=5) in the report to group the values together. There are limits to how many buckets and values you can use at once, though.